# Convert NSArray to NSMutable to remove string dynamically

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a code that I modified to pull data from an external JSON file. There are two NSArrays. One for the image and one for color. Then, when a particular array is pressed it opens a webviewcontroller. I got it to work perfectly. Here is the problem. I want to be able to modify the JSON anytime I want externally and have the app update the information but since the NSArray information is hardcoded I don't know how to remove an array if I remove an objectforkey from the JSON. Any help would be appreciated.

The code to call the images and colors is:

```
- (IBAction)onclick:(id)sender {


NSArray *images = @[

                    [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"PhoneUrl"]]],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"TextUrl"]]],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"MailUrl"]]]
                    ];
NSArray *colors = @[
                    [UIColor [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"PhoneColor"]],
                    [UIColor [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"TextColor"]]],
                    [UIColor [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"MailColor"]]],
                   ];

Sidebar *callout = [[Sidebar alloc] initWithImages:images  borderColors:colors];
callout.delegate = self;
[callout show];
```

}

Then when pressed it calls the following:

```
- (void)sidebar:(Sidebar *)sidebar didTapItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

self.webViewController = [[PBWebViewController alloc] init];

PBSafariActivity *activity = [[PBSafariActivity alloc] init];
self.webViewController.applicationActivities = @[activity];
self.webViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeMessage];

NSLog(@"Tapped item at index %lu",(unsigned long)index);
if (index == 0) {

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"PhoneWeb"]]];
     [sidebar dismissAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

if (index == 1) {

    if(![MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

        UIAlertView *warningAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Your device doesn't support SMS!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [warningAlert show];

        return;

    }
   NSArray *recipents = @[[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"TextWeb"]];
    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [messageController setRecipients:recipents];
    [[messageController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
   [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];

    [sidebar dismissAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}


if (index == 2) {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])

    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
       [[mailer navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"MailWeb"], nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    else

    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                 message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                               otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [alert show];



    }
    [sidebar dismissAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: What is the trigger for modifying the JSON (or rather knowing when it happens)? Just re-run your code to load the JSON.

Comment: i don't understand what is your problem? if you say JSON, you mean the dataDictionary? And why you declare NSArray *images and NSArray *colors if you want them mutable?

Comment: The JSON file on my web host calls the image name and color to be used in the app. I am using a premade code by someone else where the data dictionary wasn't listed. They had the image name and colors hardcoded. I changed it to call the files from the JSON file BUT I have no idea how to convert the array and make it mutable so that I can modify it on the backend and have the app change dynamically.